# Object variables are not visible from one thread to another in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety

I have two thread accessing same object RestResource, t1 thread is calling RestResource.GetResource() method and t2 thread is calling Msg variable. 
t2 thread is unable to see Msg variable data as it is changed or updated. Please advise how to fix this. 
Please note that thread t2 is starting thread t1 and waiting for it to finish the job

```
    public class RestResource()
{
    public volatile String Msg;

    public void GetResource(){
        List<Resource> remoteResourceList = GetRemoteResource(); // Getting List from Remote Server
        for (Resource resource: remoteResourceList){
            switch (resource.resourceType) {
            case 0:
                AA(); break;

            case 1:
                BB(); break;

            case 2:
                CC(); break;

            case 3:
                DD();break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void AA(){
        Msg = "AA is executing";
    }

    private void BB(){
        Msg = "BB is executing";
    }

    private void CC(){
        Msg = "CC is executing";
    }

    private void DD(){
        Msg = "DD is executing";
    }

}

private volatile RestResource restResource = new RestResource(context);
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    _restResource.GetResource();
                }
            });

    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                   t1.start();
                   while(progress<101){
                   UpdateUI(_restResource.Msg);
                   progress++;
                  }
                }
               t1.join();
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> t2 thread is unable to see Msg variable data as it change or updated.

Actually the `Msg` field is volatile. So any change on this variable will be visible for any thread that accesses it.
Your problem is that the t2 thread doesn't see the update of `Msg` because its `run()` method doesn't care of `Msg` update.
It only use it to pass it to `UpdateUI()` :

```
 UpdateUI(_restResource.Msg);
```

Then the t2 thread is finished.
To be able to use the new value of `Msg` in `t2` you should allow `t2` to not finish and to be notified as `Msg` value is changed.
In this way, it could invoke   `UpdateUI(_restResource.Msg);` with the new value.

Note that this will work but that it will add additional logic.
In fact it doesn't seem to be necessary to have a thread to invoke `UpdateUI()`.
It seems much more natural that `GetResource()` invokes directly the `UpdateUI()` method.

Comment: t2 is starting t1 thread and looping & waiting for t1 to finish the job.
All methods are executed but still UI shows AA is executing..
t2 is doing more things, so I need t2 as well.

Comment: You  much changed your code :) The answer makes no sense any longer.

Comment: Please advise how to sort it out... ))